# Checking textfield values if they are matching

Tags: javascript, validation, match, textfield

Im making a little form where you can pick your value.

If the value is not filled in correctly(I have given some example answers)
I want an alertbox to pop-up which indicates the incorrectly filled in textfields.

Cant seem to make it work...
This is what I tried

```
if(document.getElementById("BS").value.match ("thin","thick","medium")
{
    alert("Fill in the correct values");
}
```

Here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/vuc8Z/

Comment: First, I think you have typo in your "if" (The right parenthesis is missing). Second, match function expects one parameter and it is a regular expression.

Comment: You are using inappropriate controls. The Border style and thickness should be droplists (select control). The color should be a text control (HTML5 <input type='color') and the which div should also be a text item (input type='text')

Comment: was my answer useful?

Comment: @Sergio Hey, yes it is usefull, very usefull it works now, only 1 thing, I have 1 textfield which uses hexcodes, and I need it to only accept #112233 but also #AABBCC, and everything in between.

Comment: Do you mean all the colors between #112233 and #aaccbb or just those 2?

Comment: @Sergio All colors from #000000 to #FFFFFF

Comment: Updated my answer to accept all colors from #000000 to #FFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
var val = document.getElementById("BD").value;
 if (!(val == "thin" || val =="thick" || val =="medium")) {
    alert("Vul een geldige waarde in bij de aangegeven velden");
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tX2UJ/)**

Notice that you were using `getElementById("BS")`, but you wanted `BD` i think. I changed your match function to a triple `||` (or) if statement.

I moved your if statement to inside the "go" button click handler so it is fired when the button is clicked.

The match() function expects a regex, you can read more here (**MDN: [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**).

**EDIT:**

To check if the color text input is in the right format you can use this:

```
var filter = /^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$/;
if (!color.match(filter)) {
    alert('Color code Error!');
}
```

**Updated demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tX2UJ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use match method then you can use like :

```
   var str = document.getElementById("BD").value;
   if(str.match('thin') || str.match('thick') || str.match('medium')) 
   {
     alert("Fill in the correct values");
   }
```

As per my knowledge match takes regular expression as parameter and don't take multiple values.